# string to float convert error in pandas [could not convert string to float: 'dvic']

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

[image]

I'm trying to extract year from title column and convert into 'int' or 'float'. when converting it showing error(marked in yellow)

link -> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nGCdvCLUQYqU8zsEF3PaGrng-ay3IkIu?usp=sharing

Comment: Please type out the error etc. in the post, please do not link to an image or shared drive etc.Please also post the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `title` columns consists of numbers only in the form of year.

If new column named `year` is to be added to df

```
df['year'] = df.title.str.extract(r"\((\d+)\)")
```

If you want `year` as a list/series

```
year = df.title.str.extract(r'(\d+)')
```

**Output**
Added a dummy title at the last row of sample

```
    movieId title   genres  year
0   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy 1995
1   2   Jumanji (1995)  Adventure|Children|Fantasy  1995
2   3   Grumpier Old Men (1995) Comedy|Romance  1995
3   4   Waiting to Exhale (1995)    Comedy|Drama|Romance    1995
4   5   Father of the Bride Part II (1995)  Comedy  1995
5   6   Dummy 3 Title (1995)    Comedy  1995
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the last whitespace, then strip the parentheses

```py
df[['title', 'year']] = df['title'].str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
df['year'] = df['year'].str.strip('()').astype(int)
```

```
print(df)

       title  year
0  Toy Story  1995
1    Jumanji  1995
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rVJNEh9

Comment: @humptydumpty Edited my answer. I guess the error is because some values are not all number. What's the output of `df['year'].value_counts()`.

Comment: CSV File  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PLecZSVHu_me_6DP6s6zQ2YfbGSSXk9R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8XXotSU

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kIxMBY9

Comment: @humptydumpty Your data has some outliers like `141628,The Naked Truth (1957) (Your Past Is Showing),Comedy` and some movies doesn't have year. I recommend you use regex then.